# convert PDF file using path to Base64 String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to pass the path from the function for get the binary file base64 String, as like below.

```js
var file = 'dir/file.pdf';

function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}
```

But as it returning me undefined

i need similar like this

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUKJdDUxdgKNSAws2...
```

How this can be done?

Comment: This is meant to run in a web browser?

Comment: yes, it is.  using the framework angular

Answer (score 0):

With fileReader you can convert your file from path like this :

```
var file = new File("/pdf/test.pdf","r");

function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}
```

Comment: it generates the following error  'is not assignable to parameter of type '(string | ArrayBuffer | Blob | ArrayBufferView)[]'

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Lèo is good, except that it is necessary to use the good arguments for the constructor's file. Example :

```
var file = new File(["foo"], "/pdf/test.pdf", {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

Here the documentation of the Api: [File mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)